# CSS/Sass: Setting different font-sizes to a baseline – formula

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to understand how to set text to a baseline in CSS. I found out that I need to adjust the line height as soon as the font-size changes.

Some online tools and Sass mixins do exactly this, but I want to understand the formula.

For example, one mixin does it like this:

```
line-height: ceil($font-size / $page-line-height) * ($page-line-height / $font-size);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79mu6twL/) (View styles with inspect element)

For a `font-size` of `26px`, a line height of `1.84615` is calculated, based on a `$page-line-height` of `24px`.

But what exactly is calculated here, why is it working? Why is it necessary to use `ceil`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question entirely. I don't know why that mixin uses that formula, it looks overly complicated if you ask me, and not at all standard.

However, if you want to change the line-height based on the font size, just use ems, for example:

```
line-height: 1.6em;
```

This will set the line height to be 1.6 * whatever the font-size is.

To be more precise about the formula.... just do the sums

`line-height: ceil(26 / 24) * (24 / 26);
line-height: ceil(1.08) * (0.92);
line-height: 2 * 0.92;
line-height: 1.84615;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The question is actually why/how the formula I posted works for compensating the `font-size` difference. I would love to be more precise about this, but since I just don't understand it, I can't.

Comment: My answer does answer the requirement "I need to adjust the line height as soon as the font-size changes."